# How to get the integer eigenvectors of a Numpy matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, integer, scipy, eigenvector

I have a Numpy matrix, for example, `numpy.matrix([[-1, 2],[1, -2]], dtype='int')`. I want to get its **integer**-valued eigenvectors, if any; for example, `numpy.array([[-1], [1]])` for the above matrix. What Numpy returns are eigenvectors in floating numbers, scaled to have unit length.

One can do this in Sage, where one can specify the field (i.e., data type) of the matrix and operations done on the matrix will respect the field one specifies.

Any idea of how to do this nicely in Python? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess what you're referring to is Modular Arithmetic over Finite Fields? If so, then NumPy can't do it cause NumPy is for Numerics.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! No I am not doing that. Since eigenvectors of a matrix are determined up to a multiplicative constant, I am looking for a way to get the eigenvectors scaled in such a way that all the entries are integers. For example, for the matrix in my question, Numpy would return `numpy.array([[-0.70710678], [0.70710678]])` as the answer, where 0.70710678 is really srqt(2)/2 to make it a unit vector. For an arbitrary eigenvector, is there a good way to know how to rescale the vector to make it integer-valued?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am personally content with the following solution: I called `sage` in Python and let `sage` compute what I want. `sage`, being math-oriented, is rather versatile in computations involving fields other than reals.

Below is my script `compute_intarrs.py` and it requires `sage` be installed. Be aware it is a little slow.

```
import subprocess
import re
import numpy as np

# construct a numpy matrix
mat = np.matrix([[1,-1],[-1,1]])
# convert the matrix into a string recognizable by sage
matstr = re.sub('\s|[a-z]|\(|\)', '', mat.__repr__())

# write a (sage) python script "mat.py";
# for more info of the sage commands: 
# www.sagemath.org/doc/faq/faq-usage.html#how-do-i-import-sage-into-a-python-script
# www.sagemath.org/doc/tutorial/tour_linalg.html
f = open('mat.py', 'w')
f.write('from sage.all import *\n\n')
f.write('A = matrix(ZZ, %s)\n\n' % matstr)
f.write('print A.kernel()')  # this returns the left nullspace vectors
f.close()

# call sage and run mat.py
p = subprocess.Popen(['sage', '-python', 'mat.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# process the output from sage
arrstrs = p.communicate()[0].split('\n')[2:-1]
arrs = [np.array(eval(re.sub('(?<=\d)\s*(?=\d|-)', ',', arrstr))) 
        for arrstr in arrstrs]
print arrs
```

Result:

`In [1]: %run compute_intarrs.py`

`[array([1, 1])]`

Answer (score 1):

You can do some pretty cool things with `dtype = object` and the [`fractions.Fraction`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html) class, e.g.

```
>>> A = np.array([fractions.Fraction(1, j) for j in xrange(1, 13)]).reshape(3, 4)
>>> A
array([[1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4],
       [1/5, 1/6, 1/7, 1/8],
       [1/9, 1/10, 1/11, 1/12]], dtype=object)
>>> B = np.array([fractions.Fraction(1, j) for j in xrange(1, 13)]).reshape(4, 3)
>>> B
array([[1, 1/2, 1/3],
       [1/4, 1/5, 1/6],
       [1/7, 1/8, 1/9],
       [1/10, 1/11, 1/12]], dtype=object)
>>> np.dot(A, B)
array([[503/420, 877/1320, 205/432],
       [3229/11760, 751/4620, 1217/10080],
       [1091/6930, 1871/19800, 1681/23760]], dtype=object)
```

Unfortunately the `np.linalg` module converts everything to `float` before doing anything, so you can't expect to get solutions directly as integers or rationals. But you can always do the following after your computations:

```
def scale_to_int(x) :
    fracs = [fractions.Fraction(j) for j in x.ravel()]
    denominators = [j.denominator for j in fracs]
    lcm = reduce(lambda a, b: max(a, b) / fractions.gcd(a, b) * min(a, b),
                 denominators)
    fracs = map(lambda x : lcm * x, fracs)
    gcd = reduce(lambda a, b: fractions.gcd(a, b), fracs)
    fracs = map(lambda x: x / gcd, fracs)
    return np.array(fracs).reshape(x.shape)
```

It will be slow, and very sensitive to round-off errors:

```
>>> scale_to_int(np.linspace(0, 1, 5)) # [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=object)
>>> scale_to_int(np.linspace(0, 1, 4)) # [0, 0.33333333, 0.66666667, 1]
array([0, 6004799503160661, 12009599006321322, 18014398509481984], dtype=object)
```

You could mitigate some of that using the `limit_denominator` method of `Fraction`, but probably will not be all that robust.

Comment: Thank you very much Jaime for the information! I find it interesting. Unfortunately, when `numpy` scales a vector to a unit vector, the elements usually become irrational. For example, `numpy.array([1,1])` would become `numpy.array([ 0.70710678,  0.70710678])` whose elements are sqrt(2)/2. So the `fractions` module you introduced would not work for this case.